# matlab function plot not giving function graph

Tags: matlab, function, plot, piecewise

I am modelling a switch analogous to mosfet. I wrote the following code and plotted it against "x=9:0.1:11". 10 being the threshold I was expecting a step graph but it was just a horizontal line.

```
function ids = mosfet(vgs,vds)
    if vgs>=10
        ids = vds/0.028;
    else
        ids = 0;
    end
end
```

also when I change the function to the following it works giving me y=x graph.

```
 function ids = mosfet(vgs)
    ids=vgs;
 end
```

i don't understand whats the difference. Please help me getting the step graph.

Comment: You need to loop through each item in `vgs` and `vds` and *then* apply your conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function only works with scalars (a single value).
Matlab usually works with vectors and matrices.
Your example input x=9:0.1:11 is a vector and not a single value.

To make your function work when vgs is a vector or matrix and vds is a scalar, you should modify it like this:

```
function ids = mosfet2(vgs,vds)
    %check that vds is a scalar and not something else
    if length(vds)>1
        error('vds must be a scalar!')
    end

    %the actual math
    ids=zeros(size(vgs))      %create a matrix 'ids' same size as 'vgs'
                              %all initialized as zero
    ids(vgs>=10)=vds/0.028    %set new value for all 'vgs' indices >10
end
```

You can plot the curve with:

```
x=9:0.1:11
plot(x,mosfet2(x,1))
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Strange, there should be no reputation limit for accepting. It's not the same as upvoting. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DeepakSoni If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.